# H2 database can not find lowercase table name?

Tags: spring, h2, mybatis

I got an error when updating h2 data from spring + mybatis, the table "ADDRESS" can not be found. But the table name in my sql is "address", as the error message itself said.

What happened?

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ADDRESS" not found (candidates are: "address"); SQL statement:
INSERT INTO address  ( city,
street )  VALUES  ( ?,
? ) [42103-220]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Standard describes regular, delimited, and Unicode delimited identifiers. Regular identifiers are converted to case-normal form (to the upper case, excluding characters without upper-case equivalents), delimited and Unicode delimited identifiers preserve their case as is. Identifiers (in normalized form) are case sensitive.

It means that `address` = `ADDRESS` = `"ADDRESS"` = `U&"ADDRESS`, but `"ADDRESS"` != `"address"`, so you need to specify your table as `"address"` or `U&"address"`.

Some database systems aren't fully compliant with the SQL Standard in this area and use various own rules for identifiers. H2 has three compatibility settings, you can use them if you need some compatibility with one of these systems.

- You can add `;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE` to JDBC URL if you want to
  convert regular identifiers to lower case.
- You can add `;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE` to JDBC URL if you want to
  preserve case of regular identifiers as is.
- You can add `;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE` to JDBC URL if you
  need case-insensitive identifiers.

If you don't need this compatibility, most likely something is wrong with definition of your table. If it was created with `CREATE TABLE "address" (…)`, you need to use quoted `"address"` in your queries and other commands too. If you don't like it, you can change its name to `"ADDRESS"` or `address` in this definition. You can also rename this table in the existing database.